# Mysql+PHP вывод в json

Tags: php, javascript

Есть табличка, данные есть все нормально, но получаю такой результат:

```
[{"id":"1","day":null,"time":null,"what":null},{"id":"2","day":"","time":null,"what":null},{"id":"3","day":"","time":null,"what":null},{"id":"4","day":null,........
```

вот так вывожу:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `baba`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Странно, попробовал Ваш код у меня нормально все отобразилось. А в случае если вывести данные без json, они отображаются?

Comment: Строка валидная. А собственно в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Просто в вопросе есть ответ, по этому ТС не понимает что хочет.
Проблем нет, просто нужно дальше этот JSON обрабатывать и все.

Из бд достал данные, записал их в массив $rows  и дальше ты их в JSON перевел.

А что нужно то было?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос - почему приходит **null**, а не значение, то скорее всего проблема с кодировкой. 
Используйте **utf-8**.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?